# Unable to show the $.ajax results in labels

Tags: jquery, razorengine

I have created an MVC ASP.Net View using Razor and the view has a search that works just fine if I reload the view (send the search parameters to a specific
controller and then reload the view to show the due results).

However now I need to use jQuery to send the search parameters to the controller and receive/show the results in specific labels of my view. I have coded this in the search click event

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action(actionName: "PrecalificacionLibreGestion", controllerName: "Home")',
  datatype: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    NUMERO: numero,
    NIT: nit
  }),
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loader").show();
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $("#loader").hide();
    if (data.respuesta == "OK") {
      $("#lblPrecalificacion").empty();
      $("#lblAccion").empty();
      $("#lblPrograma").empty();
      $("#lblPrecalificacion").val("CODIGO PROGRAMA: " + data.codigo_programa);
      $("#lblAccion").val("ACCIÓN FORMATIVA: " + data.accion_formativa);
      $("#lblPrograma").val("PROGRAMA: " + data.precalificacion);
    }

    if (data.respuesta == "OKNO") {
      alert("no se encontró");
    }
  }
});
```

It sends the two parameters to the controller and also the controller returns the correct information according to the search parameters, but I can't manage to show the info in the `label` elements.

What I get is an empty web page with the results in JSON format as shown below:

[image]

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong please.

this is the search button

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btn-buscar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

Comment: If you see the JSON response in the browser itself I would assume that you're attempting to make this AJAX request when a `form` is being submit, but you've forgotten to stop the form submission so that the AJAX request can be made. In this case you need to call `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event that's raised. If you want more specific help on how to do that, please show more of your code - namely the event handler this AJAX request is run under

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET MVC, then consider having your action return a `PartialView` rather than JSON and simply replacing the html with the result (which would be html).  This means your empty template and your search results template can use exactly the same partial.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I just add my search button code and edit the question, you are right, so I have to use e.preventDefault() and then submit the form or just add the preventDefault()?

Comment: That's right. Although I've added an answer for you with a better method for you to use

Comment: submit buttons submit the form so you are not cancelling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're running the code under the click of the submit button the issue is that the form submission is causing a page redirect before your AJAX logic runs. To fix this you need to call `preventDefault()` on the event which is raised.

*However* a better idea again would be to hook to the `submit` event of the parent `form` element instead of the click of the button. Try this:

```
$('#yourForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    // your AJAX logic here...
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I just added the e.preventDefault() to the search button' click event but now I cannot reach the controller, the button is still submit type

Comment: In that case there may be an issue with your AJAX request. Check the console for errors